# Is it possible in rails (or elsewhere in ruby) to prevent a block from returning? Returning 50,000 records in an array takes a while

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, return, block

So I'm running a bit of logic through all of the 50,000+ records in my table (several actually, but we'll just address one here they're all the same operation) and marking boolean indicators:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.silence do
  CoreRevenue.where('core_revenues_usd IS NOT NULL').each do |c|
    c.ok = true
    c.save
  end
end
```

As you may have noticed, I've already "shut up" the database from outputting a bunch of SQL responses to the console, but there's always the big array dump at the end of the operation that can take sometimes as long as 5-10 seconds.

So I'm wondering if I can stop `x` where `x = CoreRevenue.where('core_revenues_usd IS NOT NULL')` from getting dumped after the operation is completed. Thanks.

equally 'exciting' would be an answer explaining why this is not possible due to some sort of lambda calculus computing thing or what have you

Comment: Actually "returning" the array is a very cheap - it's the usage/display of the returned value that is expensive. As noted, one way to prevent the usage is to return something else (e.g. `nil`, `[]`, `"Goodbye world!"`) that doesn't cause the post-operation to behave in the same way. This "technique" works the same for any method/function. (The only way to actually prevent returning any value is to `raise` or `throw` - or "terminate" - as these can "unwind the stack over the call-site".)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can’t prevent a block from returning, but you can just return something else instead:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.silence do
  CoreRevenue.where('core_revenues_usd IS NOT NULL').each do |c|
    c.ok = true
    c.save
  end

  nil
end
```

Comment: *nice usage of the extra block. what would you use if you didn't have one of those? 1.times{} ?

Comment: @coloradoblue Well anywhere other than the console hopefully you’re at least in a method. If you’re writing directly in the console though you can add `; nil` after the `end`.

Answer (score 2):

I would write that this way:

```
CoreRevenue.where('core_revenues_usd IS NOT NULL').update_all(:ok, true)
```

So it will run much faster than your version.

**EDIT:** Corrected with @John Neagle suggestion

Comment: This is not the same, though, as it will skip validations, callbacks, and observers since it simply runs a raw SQL `UPDATE`. Regardless,  `update_column` isn’t a method for a relation, only an ActiveRecord object.

Comment: Its an ok answer because I'm only marking a boolean and thus have no validations that need to be run through.

Comment: It only works because my logic is literally SQL. This is an interesting response. Thanks Lucas.

Comment: CoreRevenue.where('core_revenues_usd IS NOT NULL').update_all(:ok => true) might be what you are looking for.  As @AndrewMarshall points out, update_column isn't for relations.

Comment: @coloradoblue This can’t possibly be okay because it won’t even run, you’ll just get an error.